# Block output window from an executable converted from .pyw using pyinstaller

Tags: python

I recently converted a python program to an executable (.exe) but i still see an output window when i launched the executable. I don't want any output window because the program is a background process. I tried using .pyw extension before converting to an executable with no success... 
 I'm using pyinstaller to convert to executables.

Answer (score 0):

Oh nevermind, i already know how.
By using --noconsole when converting the .pyw

I think it works with .py extension too

Sorry for bad english..